# Errors working with postgreSQL in production mode Jhipster

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

I am pretty new with Jhipster development.
I developped an application with Jhipster (v 3.4.2), the application is working well with postgre in dev mode (the application is running and I can save entities in the database), but when I switch to production mode using `mvnw.cmd -Pprod`, 
the application is working well, but I can't save anything to the database (still postgre)
The odd thing is, I can see all of the created entities when in dev mode in the detailed page of the entity, but I can't add a new one in prod mode as I said. 
Both `application-dev.yml` and `application-prod.yml`files contain the same datasource (url, name, username and pass).
Moreover, there is no stacktrace when I try to save something in production mode, just an internal Server error on the page, no logs whatsoever.

thank you

Comment: Strang,e have you tried to remote debug the app? Is it just plain JHipster code or have you modified it or added your own code?

Comment: At first I tried with the app with my full own added code in it, then I tried without any code added, just with my own model, added with `jhipster-uml`, and a file created with JDL Studio. Didn't work aswell.
I didn't try without any model added.

I'll try to remote debug it also

Answer (score 0):

To build jhipster with prod profile use:

./mvnw -Pprod package  (as you already did)

Now, when starting application make sure u activete PROD profile for running app:

./jhipster-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war --spring.profiles.active=prod 
If you are on Windows, use: java -jar jhipster-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war --spring.profiles.active=prod

More details: http://jhipster.github.io/production/

Comment: Thanks, i'll try that. I thought running.  ./mvnw -Pprod   was enough